# How to rotate in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rotation

I cannot rotate on hover in IE and some browsers.

This is the css I am using:

```
.sel:hover {
    -ms-transform:rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(30deg);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of IE? Can you show the HTML to go with it? Maybe build a test case on http://jsfiddle.net (but also make sure you post the code here)

Comment: @Pekka I think that HTML is somewhat useless information as this is about crossbrowser css3.

Comment: Your question is not clear and useless without example and telling which version of IE troubles you, but you can find some usefull hints [HERE](http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/cross-browser-rotation-transformation-with-css/)

Comment: @Lollero it's *never* a mistake to see the HTML in question as well.

Comment: @Pekka well, I wouldnt say never but, in most cases its a good idea. Just that here i can clearly see that this will not work cross browser just by looking at the css and can be 100% sure that it is not about the html.

Comment: @Lollero the OP is asking about IE, for which [`-ms-transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974936(v=vs.85).aspx) is the right choice, isn't it? (As long as it's IE9.)

Comment: @Pekka Simply put.. Because life is hard. ( and theres also "..and some browsers" )

Answer (score 0):

This website gives pretty good info on this subject: 
http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/cross-browser-rotation-transformation-with-css/

Example:
http://demo.hakoniemi.net/Cross-browserRotateTransformationwithCSS/